# C++ error that says "error LinkedList Interface is an inaccessable base of linkedlist" with create link list call

Tags: c++, inheritance, singly-linked-list

I have written a class to help learn about data structures.  I've used this approach successfully before but this time it does not like `return new linkedlist();`

In file **Factory.cpp**

```
#include "list.h"
using namespace std;

LinkedListInterface * Factory::getLinkedList
{
      return new linkedlist();
}
```

In file **Factory.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "LinkedListInterface.h"
using namespace std;

class Factory
{
     public:
         static LinkedListInterface * getLinked();

};
```

file **list.h**, I have a basic constructor in this and the class is called `linkedlist`
     #include
     using namespace std;

```
 class linkedlist
 {
 private:
     typedef struct node
     {
         int data;
         node* next;
     }* nodePtr;
     nodePtr head;
     nodePtr curr;
     nodePtr temp;

  public:
         linkedlist()
         {
             head = NULL;
             curr = NULL;
             temp = NULL;
         }
   ......
   };
  there are other functions but i dont think they causing my problem.
```

This is from LinkeListInterface.h from my professor. The rest of the file are virtual methods that i made sure to include in list.h
      #pragma once
    #include

```
using namespace std;

class LinkedListInterface
{

public:

    LinkedListInterface(void){};
    virtual ~LinkedListInterface(void){};
```

Comment: Question isn't clear. I don't see any code having x and y.

Comment: Does the `linkedlist` class inherit from LinkedListInterface?

Comment: You also use `getLinkedList` in the .cpp and `getLinked` in the .h.

Comment: not to mention you left off `()`

Comment: The code you posted is **not** the code you are running.   ***Post actual code.***

Comment: Post actual code and post actual error(s)

Comment: ive edited. The LinkedListInterface.h and Factory.h files are from my professor that i cant change. He states i need to place return new "class I make"(); but im getting the error stated in the title.

Comment: Guys there is a .sh file that will be the driver from my Professor. This is a syntax problem that i cant figure out whats going on.

Comment: You have a static method which is returning a pointer to newly allocated linkedlist object. What I know is that static methods deal only with static data members. Is your linkedlist object static data member?

Comment: you're trying to convert linkedList to LinkedListInterface, and it can't do it.  one way to fix this is to make linkedList inherited from LinkedListInterface.

Comment: There is also a LinkedListInterface.h with a bunch of virtual methods. Ive made sure to add all those.  I made linkedlist inherit LinkeListInterface and the same line has the error LinkedList Interface is an inaccessable base of linkedlist. ill add LinkedListInterface.h Above from my professor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in

```
LinkedListInterface * Factory::getLinkedList
{
      return new linkedlist();
}
```

operator new return linkedlist* after called linkedlist() constructor. Here in code assume convert to LinkedListInterface * is not correct, for compile, have to convert explicitly.

```
LinkedListInterface * Factory::getLinkedList()
{
      return (LinkedListInterface* ) new linkedlist();
}
```

Comment: This will just create a runtime bug. A `linkedlist` either is a `LinkedListInterface` (i.e. it inherits from it) or it's not. If it was, the cast would be unnecessary. That compiler error says that the compiler thinks it's not.

Comment: yes, @Adam, as you said, my anwer only made compile pass. can not gurantee runtime error

Comment: That's terrible reasoning.